# Linux raw socket (layer2) - best strategy

Tags: linux, sockets, c

*The context:*

I am thinking about the best way to process packet from nic to apps.

I have 4 processes running and receiving packets from ethernet nic.

They run pf_packet sockets so they receive layer 2 packets.

The problem is that they all have to filter the packet they see.

There are no race conditions since the filtering is done by port. One app is interested in one unique port.

*The question:*

Is there a way to avoid each app to filter all the packet? Having one core for the filter and communicating the packet to the right app incurs context switch costs.

Is it possible for a nic to put the packets corresponding to custom port in a defined rx queue? That way my app will be sure that those packets are exclusively for it.

What is the best way?

Comment: Is using libpcap an option for you ? As with pcap you can easily set BPF filters to filter on various things including the port, assuming you mean UDP or TCP port.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what layer 3 and above do? Do you have a significant reason for re-inventing that wheel?

Comment: I spent the day and found about bpf and its cryptic rule syntax. Will dig into it. I cannot afford any library since i am doing a very specialized work. +1

Comment: @Larry The raw bpf interface is cryptic, but if you use libpcap you get a high level compiler that can compile and install filter strings such as "udp and port 4567" into a bpf filter with 2 function calls. If you desire, you can use just the compiler part, and attach the filters directly to your sockets that are managed outside of libpcap.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use BPF and libpcap, perhaps you can use Linux Socket Filters https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt
This will filter the packets in kernel space, before handing them to your packet sockets.

For some syntax examples, use the BSD BPF man-page https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bpf&sektion=4 or google/duckduckgo

But I also suggest that, if your application is performance critical, you prototype and measure different alternatives, before discarding any one in particular (like libpcap).